# WWW domain loading wrong ssl certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, certificate, virtualhost

If i try to load https://exampledomain.com it loads correctly and the certificate loaded is from exampledomain.com. If i try to load https://www.exampledomain.com the typical chrome warning certificate shows because it tries to load another certificate that is from another virualhost hosted in the same web server. If i press the continue button, it shows the correct virtualhost web but the certificate warning from the other virtualhost is still showing.

I can't understant why this is happening. Virtualhost seems to be correctly defined because the host is working without the www. It just dont work if I prepend the www. But the website is still correct, the only thing that is wrong is that it tries to load the certificate from another virtualhost.

Anyone has experienced something like this before? Any thoughts? Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

In order for both example.com and `www.example.com` to work with https not only the appropriate virtual host need to be defined but also the certificate must actually match the name of the host. I.e. if one accesses `www.example.com` the server certificate must actually be valid for `www.example.com` and not only for `example.com`. This does not seems to be the case in your setup.

There are basically two ways to configure this correctly: have different VirtualHost and serve different certificates, each matching the specific name of the VirtualHost. Or have a single VirtualHost section and a single multi-domain certificate which has Subject Alternative Names for both domains.

Comment: I have two different certificates and all of them are wildcards. So the common name for them are .*example.com
What would be the VirtualHost ServerName for them? .*example.com? example.com? www.example.com?

Comment: @EduRomero: The name and aliases in the VirtualHost should match the domain in the URL, i.e. for `https://www.example.com` it should be `www.example.com` or `*.example.com`. And the certificate for a VirtualHost must also cover __at minimum__ all domain names for this VirtualHost, i.e. in this case it should at least be valid for `www.example.com` (or `*.example.com` if wildcard is used in VirtualHost). And note that a plain `example.com` is not covered by `*.example.com`.

Comment: It's weird because the virtual host is correct, if I ignore the warning, the displayed website is the one that matches, but the certificate is from the other virtual host...

Comment: @EduRomero: So there is likely something wrong with either your config or the certificate. Unfortunately there is nothing reproducible known about any of these, so no further help can be given.